# Setting text to <h:inputText> jsf using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have an inputText in a popUpPanel in an xhtml page.

```
<h:graphicImage onclick="clearNewUserProfileData();" />
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{userProfileBean.firstName}"/>
```

My javascript function is

```
function clearNewUserProfileData() {                                
            $("#userProfileList\\:firstName").val('');                 
}
```

where 'userProfileList' is the id of the popUpPanel.

I do not know what is wrong here. But, the inputText is not clearing its value on click. Is this the right way to get the id of an element in jsf?

Comment: Did you receive any error in the browser console?

Comment: If you look in the rendered HTML - is the id of the element ```userProfileList:firstName```?

Comment: Don't forget to set the form attribute `prependId="false"` because if you don't, you'll get a longer IDs for your components i.e. `inputText` when it is rendered in the browser. You should be able to use `#formid:firstName` where `formid` is your form's id.

Comment: "userProfileList:firstName" is the id of the inputText that the debugging console on the browser shows.

Comment: @all : I'm able to retrieve the text of that input element and print it to the console. However, the problem is in setting the value part. To be more clear, `var text =('#userProfileList\\:firstName').val(); console.log(text);` prints whatever I give in the inputText. But, the new value that I'm trying to set, that is "" (empty string) is not getting set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the generated id of that input. In Firefox or Chrome you can do a right click - inspect on that element. 
If the id of your form is "f1" and the id of the input is "input1", this should return that DOM object:

```
$("#f1\\:input1")
```

However, if in-between you have a `<f:subview>`, the id of that subview also needs to be concatenated:

```
$("#f1\\:subview1\\:input1")
```

You can try the jQuery code directly in your browser console, to check if it's selecting the input.
If that looks ok, you need to check if the clearNewUserProfileData is reached.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to retrieve the id of an inputText element in jsf. 
It was my mistake to call the clearNewUserProfileData() function on click of the graphic image. My bad!

Indeed it was setting the value to "". But, the content was getting rendered from the bean. So, I had to call clearNewUserProfileData() in the "onshow" attribute of the pop up panel so it clears old form data from the pop up panel elements.